# How to properly edit Magento 2 stylesheets? And what to do next to see it in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, backend, less-css

I'm new to Magento 2.0. I purchased a theme and I want to edit some styles. I checked in the firebug it's showing

`url/pub/static/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/en_US/css/styles-l.css`

I made some research but I can't get clear instructions if it's ok to edit the file inside the static folder. I've read some that if I will edit it, it will be remove if I will do some `static-content:deploy`, is this true? If yes then what will I do to edit it?

I tried going to `app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/web/css/source` but I didn't find any LESS for the styles-l.css. Please can someone give me a guide on where will I edit or copy and move it from and to?

Btw, the theme inherits the Magento_Blank.

Looking forward to anyones expertise.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html

Comment: 2 quick question, is it a good practice to edit inside the pub/static folder for the stylesheet or not? Second, do I have to flush static files or static-content:deploy if I will modify stylesheet via LESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit pub folder style files(less or css),
first you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other web/css/source (common style)

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```